# bash - while with multiply conditions lose one of that

Tags: bash, while-loop

ill try to make loop with 2 conditionals, x != 0 OR curl = success, curl module working fine, but script lose [[ x -eq 0 ]]

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
x=8
while [[ $x -eq 0 ]] || [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://nexus_url/path/96."$x"/latest/version.sign)" != "200" ]]
do
  ((x--))
done
echo $x
```

when we try to use script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
x=8
while [[ $x -eq 0 ]] 
do
  ((x--))
done
echo $x
```

its succesfully stop on x=0

url checking also work, but cycle become infinity when we try use it together and no one url checking was succesfull, i think problem is in || between conditions, how i can correctly use OR in bash conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions should be like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
x=8
while [[ $x -gt 0 ]] && [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://nexus_url/path/96."$x"/latest/version.sign)" != "200" ]]
do
  ((x--))
  sleep .1
done

echo $x
```

Which is essentially this pseudo code:

```
x=8
while (x > 0 && curl_cmd != SUCCESS) {
   x--;
   skeep .1
}
```

This will attempt to run `curl` 8 times. It will come out of loop when `x==0` or `curl` returns a success.

Comment: thank you very much! && and -gt changes helped me

Comment: For readability, I'd put create a function to do the curl command: `validateVersion() { local url="http://nexus_url/path/96.${1}/latest/version.sign"; local code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' "$url"); [[ $code == "200" ]]; }` -- then you'd have `while ((x > 0)) && validateVersion "$x"; do ...`